# How to copy a file (a specific commit/version) from Git master origin repo to user Unix home directory

Tags: git, bash, unix

The scenario I encountered sound like this:

1. I  *git add*  a folder that contain bash files and python scripts as    utility tools for my project team
2. The development of main stream project's related files and the utility tools are not in sync. Meaning, I could continue update the utility tools at a different phase than the main stream project.
3. Both main stream project and the utility tools located in the same origin.
4. My concern is, while I am adding additional feature to the utility tools in future but not yet confident to release, yet I'll
   need to push my work into origin to share with other co-worker to
   continue development. I do not wish the main stream team member to
   *git pull* and accidentally use this uncompleted version.I
   want their utility tools to remain as the last official release
   version.

So my idea is to have another "install.sh", every time other team member run this utility tools, it will compare and copy/update the a stable version/commit to their Unix home directory.

1. Through this way, I could update the "install.sh" to grab the latest commit whenever I am confident to release it to the users.
   Users use *git pull* and they will get the latest "install.sh"
   always. Whenever I am not ready, no matter how many changes and push
   I did to the utility files, because the commit ID is specified by
   the "install.sh", all files that is still working will get ignored.
2. Why I suggest to copy to user's home directory? Cause I would want the same utility tool to support the user even though the user
   checkout to other branch. Also, the user are allowed to open and
   customise the tool, but their customisation shall remain in their
   own environment and not allow to push in to origin.

Anyway possible way to achieve that or am I on the wrong idea?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I understood your problem correctly - here are my suggestions:

1. Create a dev branch for the utility tools.
2. Push this dev branch to the remote so it can be accessed by everyone, with the understanding that this is a development branch and not a release branch.
3. When you're comfortable with changes in the dev branch being merged to master, only then should you do so.
4. If users customize their tools, they should be responsible for keeping these changes on a local branch of their own and merging/rebasing changes that may occur.

Comment: 1. The utility tools located in the same branch of the main project since the day one the architect designed, so it would be the best if we have a solution to maintain it.
2. The utility maintenance team are located across various area, so this make us have no better way other than push into main branch
3. The targeted user are not familiar with Git. In fact most of them migrated from Clearcase background. So unfortunately, we are not safe to assume they will take care things well.

Comment: 1. They can stay in the main branch. Different versions can also live in another branch while you work on them. 2. You can push more than one branch to the remote server using `git push origin <branch name>` 3. They should learn if they're going to be working with it.